# "Tell" in japanese

Tags: word-choice

There's a plethora of words in japanese that means "tell". For example: 言う、告げる、教える、伝える、聞く、you name it. Question is, which should I use when I just want a general "tell". For example: I want to tell you "Everything will be okay"

Comment: Think of all the [different meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell#Verb) of the English word _tell_.  Which sense you intend will change which word you use when speaking a different language.  What you describe as _"a plethora of words in Japanese that mean 'tell'"_ is a manifestation of the different mapping of concepts between English and Japanese -- where those different English meanings that just happen to be expressed by the word "tell" are instead expressed using different terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to tell you "Everything will be okay"

General case: 伝えたい
Acceptable, oral/casual: 言いたい
In case 'you' would not know in any chances: 教えたい
Inform: 告げる
In passive form: 聞かせてほしい

Comment: I want to tell you "Everything will be okay"。The "want" in this sentence is best represented by 伝えたい ということ？

I really meant 聞かせる instead of 聞く. My bad

Comment: 聞かせる still doesn't fit because 'forcing' nuance of its word. 聞いてもらう is acceptable.  The original sentence is (私はあなたがたに)「事態/状況は良くなる」と伝えたい Everything wouldn't fit すべてのこと in many cases.

Comment: I take 聞かせて as "tell me", and hence the る form of the word 聞かせる would mean "tell you"(without forcing). 違うですか

Comment: @Newbie, in that case, the subject change. "I want to be taught from you." It's Okay to use, no forcing nuance.

Comment: Soz, how did we get to 聞かせる meaning "I want to be taught from you". Do you mean "told" instead?

Comment: 聞かせる is simply 'let you hear.' "I let you hear," we don't say this in English or Japanese, but we often say "Let me hear it." =  聞かせて. And 聞きたいな = 言ってみろ = 話し給え "Do tell."